# Как заставить программу озвучить ответ

Tags: swift, xcode

Например: ответов миллион программа должна озвучить ту которую выведет на экран

Answer (score 0):

Используйте AVSpeechSynthesizer:

```
let text = "your text"
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(identifier: "en-US") 
utterance.rate = 0.40
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

Не забудьте импортировать

```
import AVFoundation
```